# Categorical Data Plot as a Function of Time - Weird Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a line (with points) that tracks the charging status of a battery charge controller over time.  As shown in the plot, R groups each of the "Categories" together, creating separate lines for each category.

My goal is to connect the lines together.  So for example, the line (from left to right) should go from MPPT - ABSORB-ABSORB-ABSORB-ABSORB-FLOAT-FLOAT-NIGHT.

How do I connect the line together without them being grouped as they currently are? My code is below.

```
    charge_status <- read.csv("charge_status.csv")

    p1 <- ggplot(data=charge_status) + 
geom_line(aes(x=as.POSIXct(hrsaftersunrise_1123,format="%H:%M"),y=chargestatus_1123,colour="Nov-23"),linewidth=1.5)+geom_point(aes(x=as.POSIXct(hrsaftersunrise_1123,format="%H:%M"),y=chargestatus_1123),size=5)+
    scale_y_discrete(limits = c("MPPT","ABSORB","FLOAT","NIGHT"),labels=c("MPPT","ABSORB","FLOAT","NIGHT"))
    p1 + plot_layout(guides="collect") & theme_fivethirtyeight() & labs(color = "Date") & scale_colour_manual(labels =c("Nov-23"), breaks =c("Nov-23"), values=c("orange")) &
    theme(plot.title = element_text(family="sans",face = "bold", size = rel(1.2), hjust = 0.0)) & theme(axis.title = element_text(size=12, face="bold")) & guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linewidth=7)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you add `group=1` to `aes()` for the plot, it should do the trick.  For example, just add `aes(group=1)` anywhere in the plot call to apply that aesthetic to all geoms.  Did you want the entire line to be orange?

Comment: Cheers, that worked.  I left the entire line as orange and can always change the dots to the colour orange as well.  Much appreciated mate.